# Jordan Normal form as consequence of the Classification theorem for finitely generated modules over PID

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, so $V\cong \mathbb{C}^n$. Let further $T:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-linear transformation. We consider $V$ as a $\mathbb{C}[X]$ module by $$p(X)\cdot v=p(T)(v).$$ 
The classification theorem for finitely generated modules over PID tells us that there exist $a_i\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $$V\cong \mathbb{C}[X]^n\oplus_i^m \mathbb{C}[X]/a_i\mathbb{C}[X]\tag{1}.$$
Now, since $V$ is finite dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$ we have $n=0$.

Here comes my question:

In my lecture notes it's written that we can show that (1) collapses into $$ V\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^m\bigoplus_{k=1}^{r_i}\mathbb{C}[X]/(X-\lambda_{i,k})^{d_{i,k}}\mathbb{C}[X] \tag{2}$$ and so we conclude that $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is the direct sum of Jordan Blocks and have proven the existence of the Jordan Normal Form.

Could someone explain how (2) follows form (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_i=\prod_{k=1}^{r_i}(X-\lambda_{i,k})^{d_{i,k}}$. Then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we have that $$\mathbb{C}[X]/a_i\mathbb{C}[X]\cong\bigoplus_{k=1}^{r_i}\mathbb{C}[X]/(X-\lambda_{i,k})^{d_{i,k}}\mathbb{C}[X]$$ then $$V\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^m\bigoplus_{k=1}^{r_i}\mathbb{C}[X]/(X-\lambda_{i,k})^{d_{i,k}}\mathbb{C}[X]$$

---

Alternatively, if you're allowed to use the primary decomposition
 form of the classification (given as [the second statement here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain)), we have a neater proof.

Over a PID, a primary ideal must be generated by an element of the form $p^s$ for some prime $p$ (see [here for an explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521429/primary-ideal-in-a-pid/2522284)). Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, primes in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ are of the form $(X-\lambda)$, so $$V\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^r\mathbb{C}[X]/(X-\lambda_i)^{s_i}\mathbb{C}[X]$$

Comment: It was originally written as $V\cong \oplus_i \oplus_k  \mathbb{C}[X]/(X-\lambda_i)^{k}\mathbb{C}[X]$ and I interpreted it wrongly as $V\cong \oplus_i^m\oplus_k^{r_i} \mathbb{C}[X]/(X-\lambda_i)^{k}\mathbb{C}[X]$. Your suggestion makes much more sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, I'm still a bit confused by that form of it to be honest! Because it looks like we're summing the same amount $\oplus_k\mathbb{C}[X]/(X-\lambda_i)^k\mathbb{C}[X]$ for each $i$, but I can't see why that should happen. Anyway though, glad it's helped, I'm going to remove the section at the start from my answer since people might be confused about what I'm pointing out about (2) now it's changed

Comment: I've also added a proof which might be simpler if you've met certain results before